# How to restart an android service when it is interrupted by reboot?

Tags: android, service

I start an android service manually which does some data collection work.

Suppose if there is interruption caused by reboot then the service ends there.I need to restart the same service on reboot.

note:I am not starting the service on boot.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to start the service when the device boots?

Comment: Do you want some kind of one-time registration to boot event? Like on Windows where is registry key "RunOnce" for this purpose.

Comment: no i start service manually and i need to restart service if there is interruption like reboot and i want to stop service i just kill the service..i need to monitor phone events for only particular duration and there should not be any inturreption

Comment: use Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED for second time when the device reboot. Just make some calculation and for every time use this intent for start the interrupted service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restart service after boot interruption.

Just store flag in shared pref which is boolean set to true if boot interrupted.

Now when boot completes you can use the following code to restart your service.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyStartupIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 // check for interreupted flag in shared pref
 // if true restart your service
}
}
```

Add following snippet to your manifest

```
<receiver android:name="MyStartupIntentReceiver">
<intent-filter>    
<action
android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Cheers....